# Changing your IP address with python but not with proxy or VPN

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

I would like to change my IP address with python but not with a proxy or VPN. I would like to let python change it in my windows settings.
I have done some research and found some ways to do it like:

```
import os
os.system('sudo ifconfig eth0 down')
os.system('sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.10')
os.system('sudo ifconfig eth0 up')
```

But here I get the output 1 which means that it didn't work and I don't understand why.
I also tried this:

```
import os
os.system('{0}\\System32\\control.exe NCPA.CPL'.format(os.environ['WINDIR']))
```

this opens the settings. But it only opens the network connections and not the wifi properties where you change the IP address. I usesd the .cpl file NCPA.CPL which apparently is the wrong one. does someone know the right cpl file or is there even a cpl file to open the wifi properties? 
And could someone explain me why my scripts don't work and maybe how it works?

Comment: Those first three are Linux commands.